# Fatal Error - Unexpectedly Found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: swift, exc-bad-instruction

I am trying to work on a chat application using swift and when I build and ran the project during the run when I try to go to the ChatVewController it shows this EXC Bad Instruction Error.

The console says

Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SportsLogin: UIViewController {

// MARK: Properties
let ref: Firebase  = Firebase(url: BASE_URL2)


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)

    let navVC2 = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
    let chatVC2 = navVC2.viewControllers.first as! SportsViewController

    chatVC2.senderId = ref.authData.uid // Assign the local user’s ID to chatVc.senderId; this is the local ID that JSQMessagesViewController uses to coordinate messages.
    chatVC2.senderDisplayName = "" // chatVc.senderDisplayName is set to empty string, since this is an anonymous chat room.
}



@IBAction func loginDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

    ref.authAnonymouslyWithCompletionBlock { (error, authData) -> Void in
        if error != nil {  // Check for an authentication error.
            print(error.description)
            return
        }
        // Inside of the closure, trigger the segue to move to ChatViewController.
        print(self.ref.authData)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SportChat", sender: self)
    }

}

}
```

The Line with the error is

```
chatVC2.senderId = ref.authData.uid // Assign the local user’s ID to chatVc.senderId; this is the local ID that JSQMessagesViewController uses to coordinate messages.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use a breakpoint at chatVC2.senderId = ref.authData.uid and try to print(chatVC2.senderId = ref.authData.uid). check if it is printing properly.

Answer (score 0):

What are the SportsViewController ? if SportViewController is delcare by yourself, you should have the member of variable is sendId, is class memeber and NSString type.

Comment: So basically SportsLogin is my login screen or a button going to a chat screen and the SportsViewController is the chat screen. @RYANCOAL9999